# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to implement a filter using

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory) {
        this.filterFactory = filterFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("resource", r -> r.path("/resource")
                        .filters(f -> f.filters(filterFactory.apply())
                                .removeRequestHeader("Cookie"))
                        .uri("http://resource:9000"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I use Spring Cloud version `2021.0.0` and this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

P.S

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test.gateway'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0")
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Error stack:

```
Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.ReactiveCommonsClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.availability.AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.integration.IntegrationMetricsAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.CommonsConfigAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



23:02:34.410 [main] DEBUG LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter[report:37] - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
        at org.MerchantHubGatewayApplication.main(MerchantHubGatewayApplication.java:11)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
23:02:34.411 [main] ERROR LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter[report:40] -

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.gateway.security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Add `--debug=true` cli argument to see the auto configuration report. You're likely missing a dependency or property to enable it

Comment: Search in the report for token relay. You'll need spring security for sure

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 things to verify here:

1. TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory should be a @component/@service/@repository.
2. If yes, spring is not able to find it in the path. Hence you need to use @ComponentScan() to specify which basePackages it has to search and you will be able to overcome this issue.

Comment: the comment is irrelevant